# Android Studio fails to load the Visual Layout Editor

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been on google and android support forums for more than 8 hours now with no luck. My Android studio was working fine 2 days ago and last night when I wanted to continue my project, I got this error :

```
    Render error
    ActiveTool: com.intellij.designer.designSurface.tools.SelectionTool@7797899
    SDK: Android 4.4.2 - API 19
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kxml2/io/KXmlParser
    at com.android.ide.common.resources.IdResourceParser.parse(IdResourceParser.java:75)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.IdGeneratingResourceFile.parseFileForIds(IdGeneratingResourceFile.java:150)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.IdGeneratingResourceFile.load(IdGeneratingResourceFile.java:72)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceFolder.getFile(ResourceFolder.java:286)
at com.android.ide.common.resources.ResourceFolder.processFile(ResourceFolder.java:74)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.FrameworkResourceLoader$IdeFrameworkResources.ensureInitialized(FrameworkResourceLoader.java:124)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.FrameworkResourceLoader.loadPlatformResources(FrameworkResourceLoader.java:60)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.FrameworkResourceLoader.load(FrameworkResourceLoader.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getFrameworkResources(AndroidTargetData.java:207)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache.getFrameworkResources(ResourceResolverCache.java:248)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache.getFrameworkResources(ResourceResolverCache.java:214)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.ResourceResolverCache.getResourceResolver(ResourceResolverCache.java:129)
at com.android.tools.idea.configurations.Configuration.getResourceResolver(Configuration.java:1137)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.getResourceResolver(RenderService.java:276)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:469)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:483)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser          PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:68)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 30 more
```

Anyone got some thoughts on this? Oh yeah, The first time I used android studio, it was online, then it work, then offline, still worked and now it doesn't work again.

My setup :

Windows 8.1 pro 64-bit
Java JDK 1.7 64-bit

I tired changing the API level, but still no results. Here is a screenshot :

http://snag.gy/bSr7y.jpg

If there is already a thread on this, please point me to it and I'll remove this one. I did a quick search on StackOverflow and couldn't see anything.

Thanks in advance

**Solution :**

Turns out, my JDK was corrupt and it didn't fully remove the installation when uninstalled.

I finally got it fixed. Here is what I did :

First, I uninstalled Java JDK1.7 and removed all it's left over files.
Then I downloaded and installed JDK1.8 and it worked.

I had an error where the Studio said it couldn't detect JDK, so I only added an JAVA_HOME environment variable which points to my new JDK and it's all working fine now. Thanks everyone for the help and suggestions. I hope this can help someone in the future.

Comment: "Early Access java versions may cause compatibility issues. Please use stable release." < Have you tried finding out what the IDE wants to tell you with that?

Comment: @dawnkeeper : I tried using different java versions also with no luck. The jdk is the same one I used before when it still worked

Comment: This issue looks familiar to me. Is this issue happening only if you try to load the visual layout editor? Are you able to continue editing the layouts in text mode and build the app? If the answer is yes, then it may be issue with JDK 1.7. Try with JDK 1.6.

Comment: @gnuanu : That's exactly it! Only the visual editor doesn't wanna load. Everything else works fine. I will try using 1.6 and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what the exact problem was ...
But NoClassDefFoundError is kind of hard ...
Anyway try this post

[3 ways to solve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Check the XmlParser class (try commenting any class calls)
above link describes how this error gets  generated